How to exclude files from running in testResource
Trying to exclude the files in path "/path/to/exclude/" while running the unit test cases in
"path/to/directory" . Unfortunately the following snippet is not working in pom.xml
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>path/to/directory</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/path/to/exclude/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
           <directory>path/to/resources</directory>
       </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>


If they will be excluded than the question why are they in that directory anyway?
